# C program to read from a file and print out only those words start with a specific char from a text file in another text file

Tags: c

I am trying to write a code which will read a file "part1.txt" and print/ write to a file named "part2.txt" only those words from "part1.txt" which begin with the char "@" , however in the current code the user can input any char and the output is words starting with that char.

So while running the code , it prompts `Letter:` and I input `@` .

But it's output is showing `Segmentation fault, core dumped` . Can you please explain what am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

char getNxtPntdVal(FILE *fPntr) {
char holder;
holder = fgetc(fPntr);
return holder;
}


void writeToFile(char c){
FILE *fpt = fopen("/home/xyz/part2.txt","a");
fputc(c,fpt);
fclose(fpt);
}

int main() {

FILE *filePtr;

char arrChar[50000];
char name[30];
char letter;
char ch;
char ch2;
int charNum=0;
filePtr = fopen("/home/xyz/part1.txt","r");
printf("Letter:");
letter=getchar();



while((ch=fgetc(filePtr))!=EOF){
    if(ch==letter && charNum ==0) {
        ch2 = ch;
        while (ch2 != '\n') {
            printf("%c", ch2);
            writeToFile(ch2);
            ch2 = getNxtPntdVal(filePtr);
        }
        charNum=charNum+1;
        printf("\n");
        writeToFile('\n');

    } else if(ch=='\n') {
        charNum=0;
    }else{
        charNum=charNum+1;
    }
    }
 }
```

Comment: `while (ch2 != '\n') {` This could loop indefinitely if there is no newline in the file.

Comment: So it creates problem in the final line of the ffile? Can you please tell me what can I add?